# React cannot read passed args from docker in runtime

Tags: reactjs, docker

I have a react application where I want to access to docker args passed when using the CLI like the following:

```
docker container run -it -p 3001:80 --env MYENV=MYENV myimage
```

and in my react app just consume it, I have tried the following in my dockerfile:

```
ARG MYENV
ENV MYENV ${MYENV}
```

but this works only in build time and not in runtime, any idea?

Comment: Are you using CRA?

Answer (score 0):

You can set MYENV value during image creation time.

docker build --build-arg MYENV=LOCAL -t image_name:tag_name .

and check using below command :-

docker inspect image_id

Output :-

[image]

Now This is the Default value will be used during Container Creation

docker run -it -p 3004:80 image_name:tag_name

you can verify using docker inspect container_id

[image]

in case you want to override it use

docker run -it -p 3004:80 --env MYENV=Prod image_name:tag_name

Note :- It will help you in case any issue please let me know